# Media library style not loading correctly when selecting a page featured image?

Tags: css, media-library

I'm trying to set a featured image to some pages, so when I press select featured images the media library upload UI not loading correctly its own stylesheet ( get images and search are working perfectly)

This is a screenshot of the problem
and the thing is the problem occurs only on some pages ( with the same template!!! )

[image]

**What I've tried:**

1. Checked every single plugin deactivate&activate ( no changes)
2. Add a `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` in  `wp-config.php` file ( no changes)
3. Checked console there are no errors.
4. Different browsers on 2 different devices ( no changes )

Any ideas would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You posted an answer where you clarified it was ACF, but in your question above you said the problem persisted with plugins deactivated.  Do ACF blocks still execute even when the plugin is deactivated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, the problem was in the pages which contains ACF blocks

ACF plugin is not compatible with the latest WP 5.9.1

temporary fixes until the update has been released :

1- In your **functions.php** file add these lines:

```
 function acf_fix_preload_path( $preload_paths ) {
        global $post;
        $rest_path   = rest_get_route_for_post( $post );
        $remove_path = add_query_arg( 'context', 'edit', $rest_path );
        return array_filter(
            $preload_paths,
            function( $url ) use ( $remove_path ) {
                return $url !== $remove_path;
            });}
        add_filter( 'block_editor_rest_api_preload_paths', 'acf_fix_preload_path', 10, 1 );
```

**Or**
rollback to the previous version of WordPress like 5.9